# Redirect user based on their type

Tags: java, php, android

I am trying to make a login page in which there are 3 types of users: student, staff, admin and once they login they get redirected to their specific activities. The users would be stored in a field in the DB which will be called user_type. What do I need to add in order to make this work?

Login.php

```
<?php


require_once 'include/DB_Functions.php';
$db = new DB_Functions();


$response = array("error" => FALSE);

if (isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {


    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];


    $user = $db->getUserByEmailAndPassword($email, $password);

    if ($user != false) {

        $response["error"] = FALSE;
        $response["uid"] = $user["unique_id"];
        $response["user"]["name"] = $user["name"];
        $response["user"]["email"] = $user["email"];
        $response["user"]["created_at"] = $user["created_at"];
        $response["user"]["updated_at"] = $user["updated_at"];
        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {

        $response["error"] = TRUE;
        $response["error_msg"] = "Login credentials are wrong. Please try again!";
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
} else {

    $response["error"] = TRUE;
    $response["error_msg"] = "Required parameters email or password is missing!";
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

DB_Functions.php

```
<?php


class DB_Functions {

    private $conn;

    // constructor
    function __construct() {
        require_once 'DB_Connect.php';
        // conectare BD
        $db = new Db_Connect();
        $this->conn = $db->connect();
    }

    // destructor
    function __destruct() {

    }


    public function storeUser($name, $email, $password) {
        $uuid = uniqid('', true);
        $hash = $this->hashSSHA($password);
        $encrypted_password = $hash["encrypted"]; // incriptare parola
        $salt = $hash["salt"]; // salt

        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO users(unique_id, name, email, encrypted_password, salt, created_at) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, NOW())");
        $stmt->bind_param("sssss", $uuid, $name, $email, $encrypted_password, $salt);
        $result = $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();

        // verifica stocarea cu succes
        if ($result) {
            $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?");
            $stmt->bind_param("s", $email);
            $stmt->execute();
            $user = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
            $stmt->close();

            return $user;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }


    public function getUserByEmailAndPassword($email, $password) {

        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?");

        $stmt->bind_param("s", $email);

        if ($stmt->execute()) {
            $user = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
            $stmt->close();

            // verifica parola
            $salt = $user['salt'];
            $encrypted_password = $user['encrypted_password'];
            $hash = $this->checkhashSSHA($salt, $password);

            if ($encrypted_password == $hash) {
                // informatiile scrise sunt corecte
                return $user;
            }
        } else {
            return NULL;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Verifica daca user exista
     */
    public function isUserExisted($email) {
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT email from users WHERE email = ?");

        $stmt->bind_param("s", $email);

        $stmt->execute();

        $stmt->store_result();

        if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
            // user exista 
            $stmt->close();
            return true;
        } else {
            // user nu exista
            $stmt->close();
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Incriptare parola
     */
    public function hashSSHA($password) {

        $salt = sha1(rand());
        $salt = substr($salt, 0, 10);
        $encrypted = base64_encode(sha1($password . $salt, true) . $salt);
        $hash = array("salt" => $salt, "encrypted" => $encrypted);
        return $hash;
    }

    /**
     * Decriptare parola

     */
    public function checkhashSSHA($salt, $password) {

        $hash = base64_encode(sha1($password . $salt, true) . $salt);

        return $hash;
    }

}

?>
```

LoginActivity.java

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = RegisterActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private Button btnLogin;
    private Button btnLinkToRegister;
    private EditText inputEmail;
    private EditText inputPassword;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private SessionManager session;
    private SQLiteHandler db;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
        inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
        btnLinkToRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLinkToRegisterScreen);

        // Progress dialog
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);

        // SQLite database handler
        db = new SQLiteHandler(getApplicationContext());

        // Session manager
        session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());

        // Check if user is already logged in or not
        if (session.isLoggedIn()) {
            // User is already logged in. Take him to main activity
            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }

        // Login button Click Event
        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {
                String email = inputEmail.getText().toString().trim();
                String password = inputPassword.getText().toString().trim();

                // Check for empty data in the form
                if (!email.isEmpty() && !password.isEmpty()) {
                    // login user
                    checkLogin(email, password);
                } else {
                    // Prompt user to enter credentials
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Please enter the credentials!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }
            }

        });

        // Link to Register Screen
        btnLinkToRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        RegisterActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }
        });

    }

    /**
     * function to verify login details in mysql db
     * */
    private void checkLogin(final String email, final String password) {
        // Tag used to cancel the request
        String tag_string_req = "req_login";

        pDialog.setMessage("Logging in ...");
        showDialog();

        StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Method.POST,
                AppConfig.URL_LOGIN, new Response.Listener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Login Response: " + response.toString());
                hideDialog();

                try {
                    JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                    boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");

                    // Check for error node in json
                    if (!error) {
                        // user successfully logged in
                        // Create login session
                        session.setLogin(true);

                        // Now store the user in SQLite
                        String uid = jObj.getString("uid");

                        JSONObject user = jObj.getJSONObject("user");
                        String name = user.getString("name");
                        String email = user.getString("email");
                        String created_at = user
                                .getString("created_at");

                        // Inserting row in users table
                        db.addUser(name, email, uid, created_at);

                        // Launch main activity
                        Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,
                                MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                    } else {
                        // Error in login. Get the error message
                        String errorMsg = jObj.getString("error_msg");
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // JSON error
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Json error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Login Error: " + error.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                hideDialog();
            }
        }) {

            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                // Posting parameters to login url
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("email", email);
                params.put("password", password);

                return params;
            }

        };

        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);
    }

    private void showDialog() {
        if (!pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.show();
    }

    private void hideDialog() {
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Comment: *What do I need to add in order to make this work?* means ?? I didn't get you ?? what is working and not ?

Comment: Your PHP code could return a field that says the type of the user and then the java could just have a switch to start the correct activity

Comment: @Ravi at this moment the login works for all the users redirecting them to the same activity. What I want is to be able to redirect them to different activities based on their role set in the DB.

Comment: @Iitelite how exactly would I be able to do that?

Comment: Depending upon email id you need to find type of user. Depending upon type of user you need to redirect user to respective page.

Answer (score 0):

Do as @litelite said, and add a return with the type of the user. WHat you can return is an integer, with `0-x` where `x` is the amount of login-types(student, teacher, admin, etc).

AFter you have returned the logintype, you have some options:

1. Intent.putExtra(or Bundle)

In this code:

```
    if (session.isLoggedIn()) {
        // User is already logged in. Take him to main activity
        Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
```

before starting the activity, add:

```
intent.putExtra("usertype", userType);
```

And in the receiving activity, add:

```
int userType = getIntent().getIntExtra("usertype", -1);//-1 is the default. If you use -1 for something, change it to any other number
```

If you aren't familiar with get and putExtra, when using getExtra the last input is a default value. Meaning if it cannot be found, throw a new exception or redirect back to the login screen, whatever you feel like.

2. Multiple activities

This is different from above, as the above method assumes there is one activity where things are handled. FOr this method, you create one activity per login-type, and in the login activity you create an intent where you redirect to the appropriate class. You find the appropriate class by the integer input received from the login script.

3. static fields

You can add a static field in MainActivity to receive the integer from the login-script. Something to note is that you have to set it to -1 as default to make sure you receive input.

---

How you get the user type is up to you. You can access it from the database or return it from the PHP method.

**To get data into Java from the PHP script**

Apparently, you cannot just return the integer from a method. Using Volley makes it not that easy, as it isn't plain PHP or plain Java.

I was not aware you were using volley, and as I do not know how to use Volley, I will point you in the right direction.

You already use JSON to get data from the script. When you add data into the JSON object, add the integer with the user type. Then retrieve it, add it to the class(as a local variable, just save it so it can be used elsewhere later. If it is in the same method, you put it in the method, if not in the class).

Now that you have retrieved the integer, it may be in the form of a String. So you have to convert it from a string to integer by doing `usertype = Integer.parseInt(stringInt)`. Now you can go and do one of the three steps I described earlier in the post. This will allow you to make sure the different users get a different experience(admins get access to what they need and students what they need)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, In the php I went for `echo $user['type'];` ,but I don't know exactly what and where to add in order to make this work. My login screen and the connection was done using this [tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite)

Comment: Are you able to retrieve the usertype using echo? Especially considering echo prints text (or HTML/CSS/JavaScript) to the screen and not returning it

Comment: I am doing some research, going to update the answer when I find something